# Portworx cluster down and unable to expand node pool

Tags: azure-aks

I'm new to portworx so I am a bit stuck

PX storage down and cant expand pool size

I'm running portworx on my kubernetes cluster and I noticed the pods arent in a running state.

Looks like my portworx cluster is down . I saw the storage was only 150GB so I tried increasing to 2TB and I have the below

```
sh-4.4# /opt/pwx/bin/pxctl service pool show
PX drive configuration:
Pool ID: 0 
    Type:  Default 
    UUID:  94t32on1-8d04-4fe1-34okk-0ff51dbf2610 
    IO Priority:  LOW 
    Size: 150 GiB 
    Status: Offline 
    Has metadata:  Yes 
    Balanced:  Yes 
    Drives:
    1: /dev/sdc, Total size 150 GiB, Online
    LastOperation  OPERATION_RESIZE 
        Status:  OPERATION_PENDING 
        Message: waiting on volumes: [pvc-44cbd489-224a-4db3-96fa-f0d52eabd3a2] to be clean before starting pool expansion to 2048 GiB
    Cache Drives:
    No Cache drives found in this pool
```

I ran a status and I see this

```
sh-4.4# ./pxctl status
Status: PX storage down
Telemetry: Healthy
Metering: Healthy
License: PX-Enterprise Usage Based (expires in 2954 days)
Node ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    IP: 172.29.152.138 
    Local Storage Pool: 1 pool
    POOL    IO_PRIORITY RAID_LEVEL  USABLE  USED    STATUS  ZONE        REGION
    0   LOW     raid0       150 GiB 135 GiB Offline eastus2-3   eastus2
    Local Storage Devices: 1 device
    Device  Path        Media Type      Size        Last-Scan
    0:1 /dev/sdc    STORAGE_MEDIUM_MAGNETIC 150 GiB     21 Apr 23 17:32 UTC
    total           -           150 GiB
    Cache Devices:
     * No cache devices
Cluster Summary
    Cluster ID: clustername
    Cluster UUID: 1a878482-56669-4nbin-bef4-477389ba317b
    Scheduler: kubernetes
    Nodes: 9 node(s) with storage (5 online), 12 node(s) without storage (12 online)
    IP      ID                  SchedulerNodeName
```